# Conditional Statement in JS is not working in the below code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const myFunction = (props) => {
  let myCondition = false;
  console.log('-----****----',props);

  if(props && props.isAllowed) {
    myCondition = true;
  }
  
  if(someOtherCondition) {
    return(
      <li><Link className="vx_globalNav-links" to="#">Policies</Link>
        <ul>
          <li><Link className="vx_globalNav-links" to="/my-policy">My Policy</Link></li>
          { myCondition && (<li><Link className="vx_globalNav-links" to="/condition-policy">Condition Policy</Link></li>)}
  
        </ul>
      </li>
    );
  }
  return null;
};
```

The above code seems to be not working for condition based link to display on UI for "Condition policy" even though I get "true" for "myCondition" in the console log which is just logged before the return statement. Wondering What's wrong here. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: `if(someOtherCondition) console.log('', myCondition); {` won't work. Is that meant to be an `if/else` condition?

Comment: Sorry, I missed it while pasting here . I just updated now. I removed the console.log now and "someOtherCondition" is true now. 

Also, myCondition is true but "Condition Policy" Link is not being shown up on UI

Comment: Now that you've edited the question, you've kind of invalidated the existing answers and now, the code isn't enough to figure out what's the issue. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you put a statement immediately after your `if()` statement, and so your block of code within `{ ... }` is not executed as part of your `if` statement.

```js
if(someOtherCondition)
    console.log('', myCondition);
  {
    return(
```

The curly braces must follow immediately after the `if()` statement, otherwise, as it is in this case, the `console.log` is executed when `someOtherCondition` is true. And whatever is within `{ ... }` is executed anyway regardless.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the below link,
If you are something is not right, then please comment.

https://playcode.io/873851/

- If you put a condition without `{` just after the if statement, then the rest of the code does not depend on the condition.

Answer (score -2):

**Your if statement syntax is wrong**

Comment: Is it workable?   ** if(someOtherCondition)
    console.log('', myCondition);
  { **

Comment: Sorry, I missed it while pasting here . I just updated now. I removed the console.log now and "someOtherCondition" is true now. Also, myCondition is true but "Condition Policy" Link is not being shown up on UI

Comment: It's okay, also give me + reputation